# How to setup portforwarding

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have the following setup.

Local -- server A -- server B

I need to scp, ssh from Local to B. What I do now is I scp/ssh to A and then from A to B.I would like to know how to setup portforwarding, so i can do ssh to a specific port and i driectly reach server B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a reverse SSH tunnel.

Server B is on a network behind a NAT or firewall you don't have control over. In this case port-forwarding on the router wouldn't be possible.

**2021 Update:** use the ProxyCommand or ProxyJump options instead: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump

**ProxyCommand:**

Add the following to your ssh config at `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server-b
  ProxyCommand ssh user@server-a -W %h:%p
```

You can even do this on the command line:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p server-a" server-b
```

**ProxyJump:**

SSH version 7.3 and upwards have the `-J` flag for `ProxyJump`:

```
ssh -J user@<server-a:port> <user@server-b:port>
```

**Original answer:**

In a reverse tunnel, you tunnel the connection to B via the publicly accessible A. To do this, you SSH from B -> A with a port-forward specified on the command line.

```
    ssh user@server-a -L 2222:server-b:22 -fN
```

Then SSH from Local -> A with your forwarded port specified:

```
    ssh -p2222 server-b-user@localhost
```

... which would connect you to server B.

**Sources:**
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump (2021)

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

You might also want to use `autossh` if you want to automatically create and keep open your connection.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/automatically-restart-ssh-sessions-and-tunnels-using-autossh.html